# Mac OSX Lion on Virtualbox video driver

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I recently installed Max OS X Lion (iAtkos L1) on Virtualbox (host: Windows 7). Everything works fine but the graphics. As I am only able to assign only 256 M of cram to it and 3D accelerator seems to do nothing at all.

I wonder if anybody managed to make graphics better on this situation?

Comment: Questions about Hackintoshes are off topic here. We can't help you if your pirated installation doesn't work perfectly. It was never meant to do so.